# SQL Server, how to call view in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a question for SQL Server Management Studio.

How can I call view in a stored procedure?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried just calling the view as you would a table?

Comment: You don't **call** a view - you just **select** from it, like from a table .....

Answer (score 4):

I really cant understand what you want to know or to do.
This is useless code, but maybe it can be helpfull:

```
use [AdventureWorks2012]
GO
create view dbo.EMP
as
SELECT [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[NationalIDNumber]
      ,[LoginID]
      ,[OrganizationNode]
      ,[OrganizationLevel]
      ,[JobTitle]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[MaritalStatus]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[HireDate]
      ,[SalariedFlag]
      ,[VacationHours]
      ,[SickLeaveHours]
      ,[CurrentFlag]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]
  where jobtitle = N'Research and Development Manager'
  GO

  create procedure dbo.p_select_from_EMP_view
  as
  begin
  select * from dbo.EMP
  end
  GO

  exec dbo.p_select_from_EMP_view
```

Answer (score 4):

Question has 1000+ views

```
SELECT * FROM ViewName
```